# Array items not pushed into async.queue

Tags: javascript, arrays, asynchronous, stripe-payments, async.js

I have an array of customers, of which I created a queue to charge each of them. It charges the first customer but does not push the next customer to the queue. What am I missing, please? Below is my code.

```
let q = async.queue(async(customer, callback) =>{
   let r =  await stripe.charges.create({
            amount: customer.amount ,
            currency: "usd",
            customer: customer.customerId,
            source: customer.token
        }, {
            idempotency_key: customer.uuid
        });  
 },1)
 async.forEach(customers, async(customer, callback)=> {
   q.push(customer, function(err){
        if(err){
            console.log(err,"errr==========")
        }
    })
 })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing async/await with callbacks here, and you're never calling the `async.forEach()` callback.

```
let q = async.queue((customer, callback) => {
  stripe.charges.create({
    amount: customer.amount ,
    currency: "usd",
    customer: customer.customerId,
    source: customer.token
  }, {
    idempotency_key: customer.uuid
  }, callback);  
},1)

customers.forEach((customer) => {
  q.push(customer, (err, cus) => {
    if(err){
      console.log(err,"errr==========")
    }

    // Do whatever
  })
});
```

You also want to make sure that `customer.token` is a Card ID, not a Token ID; if it's the Token ID you used to create the Customer, then you don't need it, and if it's a new card token, you need to either update the Customer first or add it to the Customer.